# Python: multiple loggers write logs into similar file

Tags: python, logging

Based on the requirement, I need to generate separate log file for all input and that will go to separate directory. The code is as follows -

```
def setup_logger(logger_name, log_filename):
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_filename, 'w')
    formatter = logging.Formatter(_FORMAT)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    return logger
```

this function will be called before processing an input -

```
logger = None

def foo(input_string):
    global logger
    logger = setup_logger('app', '/opt/data/'+input_string+'.log')

    # do processing and dumping into logs
    # this function will call one recursive function to process data
    logger = None # destroying logger object

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    for inp in sys.argv[1:]:
        foo(inp)
```

Now my problem is - in one log file, there are logs for the expected input_string but along with that there will be logs for other input_strings - appended at last.
And those logs will also be there in their log files.

Any idea for this weird problem??

Comment: so '/opt/data/'+argv[0]+'.log' contains log for '/opt/data/'+argv[1]+'.log'?

Comment: @user3125280 No.. It has logs for argv[2] or argv[3] or both too. - no specific pattern as such..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)` call will always return the same `Logger` object for a given `logger_name`. What happens here is that you add one more `FileHandler` to the "app" logger each time you call `setup_logger`.

Try and remove all handlers first, e.g.:

```
def setup_logger(logger_name, log_filename):
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_filename, 'w')
    formatter = logging.Formatter(_FORMAT)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # Replace the previous handlers with the new FileHandler
    for old_handler in logger.handlers:
        logger.removeHandler(old_handler)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    return logger
```